# MapReduce realtime projects with code

Tags: mapreduce

I would like to take a look at Code of  big mapreduce job.
Please give  me some idea about real mapreduce project with real time usecases

Answer (score 0):

[From wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

> MapReduce is useful in a wide range of applications, including
>   distributed pattern-based searching, distributed sorting, web
>   link-graph reversal, term-vector per host, web access log stats,
>   inverted index construction, document clustering, machine learning,[8]
>   and statistical machine translation. Moreover, the MapReduce model has
>   been adapted to several computing environments like multi-core and
>   many-core systems,[9][10][11] desktop grids,[12] volunteer computing
>   environments,[13] dynamic cloud environments,[14] and mobile
>   environments.[15]
>
> At Google, MapReduce was used to completely regenerate Google's index
>   of the World Wide Web. It replaced the old ad hoc programs that
>   updated the index and ran the various analyses.[16]
>
> MapReduce's stable inputs and outputs are usually stored in a
>   distributed file system. The transient data is usually stored on local
>   disk and fetched remotely by the reducers.

Follow the link and read the papers for source code.

Comment: It is, top of the answer, blue "link" text.